# How to apply specific function over a list in r?

Tags: r

Good morning!

Suppose i have the following list in r :

```
l=list(c(1,2,30),c(5,5,5))
```

My question is very simple but I failed to get the right answer !

How can i apply a function over rows/columns to get the following outputs :

```
l_sum_of_rows=list(33,15)

l_sum_of_columns=list(6,7,35)
```

Such things are very easy to acheive with matrices . However , I don't know how to do same with lists.

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: I had found a soltion for rows : sapply(l, sum) , what about columns ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think of your data as rows and columns, you should make that list a data.frame. Anyway, the first task is easy with `lapply`:

```
sapply(l, sum)
#[1] 33 15
```

For the second task you can use `do.call` if you have a length-two list:

```
do.call("+", l)
#[1]  6  7 35
```

For longer lists, you can use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("+", l)
#[1]  6  7 35
```

Comment: @KarthikS Thanks. Any R user should know these functions by heart.

Answer (score 1):

Lists of vectors of equal length are (almost) data.frames and there is a lot of specialty functions for those.

```
l <- list(c(1,2,30),c(5,5,5))
ld <- as.data.frame(l)
rowSums(ld)   # sums of rows
colSums(ld)   # sums of columns
```

Comment: Yes , i wanted to avoid changing data type because i have a list equivalent to a matrix of ( 150*4). Thank you a lot for this remark!

Comment: These functions are for matrices. Their first step when you pass a data.frame is `as.matrix`. That step can be inefficient for larger data.